# PHP Message success function [HELP]

Tags: php

anyone help me with my contact form? it will not work, it sends a message but no confirmation of message succes? everything works fine exceptg the Message succesfull send function :(

here are the codes hope someone can help me

Contact.php

```
<?php

@error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
@ini_set('display_errors', true);
@ini_set('html_errors', true);
@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "info@arjen079.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Application Website!";
    $email_noreply = "noreply@arjen079.com";
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required
    $email_message = "Form Details Below:\n\n";
    $email_messagesender = "Here is a copy of the form you filled in:\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    $email_messagesender .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_messagesender .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_messagesender .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";

    $email_messagesender .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


    // send a copy to sender

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_noreply."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_noreply."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($email, "Thanks For contacting!", "Thanks for contacting me, I will reply to you shortly. \n\n----------------\n\n" . $email_messagesender, $headers);
    echo 'Message Succesfully Sent!<script>$(\'response-message\').text(\'Message Succesfully Sent!\');var form = document.getElementById("contact-form");form.reset();</script>';

}
?>
```

Contact form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="span7">
                    <form action="http://www.arjen079.com/contact.php" method="post" class="contact-form"                                                   id="contact-form">
                            <h1>Contact</h1>
                            <hr class="fancy-hr">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="required">
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="required">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="required">
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" class="required"></textarea>
                            <div class="response-message"></div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="float-right">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    </form>
```

Thanks already! ;)

Comment: If you need help, you should atleast have a minimal understanding of what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'Message Succesfully Sent!<script>$(\'response-message\').text(\'Message Succesfully Sent!\');var form = document.getElementById("contact-form");form.reset();</script>';
```

The error is in this part.

`$(\'response-message\')` should be `$(\'.response-message\')`.

Notice the `.` you're missing? You're trying to target the ELEMENT called response-message, not the div with the class of it.

Comment: @ArjenDenDulk Just tested it, works fine for me. Try hard-refreshing your browser (Ctrl + F5)

Comment: not working? even cleared my browser cache/cookies did you tested my website?

Comment: @ArjenDenDulk Works fine on my end in Chrome. http://prntscr.com/53mhoj Do you get any errors in your console?